# How zip a file inside a docker contanier?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, compression, containers

I have exported a very large file inside mongo container in Ubuntu. I just wondering how I can zip a file inside a docker container?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using mongoDump. First, enter your target container by `docker exec -it containerName bash`

Then, Inside the container run the following command to dump and zip the file:

```
mongodump --db somedb --collection yourCollectionName --out - | gzip > collectiondump.gz
```